# Dynamically setting html attribute lang does not change the locale in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to dynamically set the locale by setting "lang" attribute of html :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("html").attr("lang","ko-KR");// or "en-us"
 });
```

The below code  does not work :

```
<input id="date" type="date"> .
```

The date format works when I set the locale in html page but doesn't work when I dynamically set it through jquery.
However if I directly set in the html page it works :

```
<html lang="ko-KR">
```

Let me know where I am going wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may need to reload the page after setting it

Comment: And working/not working means what exactly …?

Comment: <input id="date" type="date"> . The date format works when I set locale in html page but doesnot work when I dynamically set it through jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this article: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations.

> If you want to create metadata that describes the language of the intended audience of a page, rather than the language of a specific range of text, do so by getting the server to send the information in the HTTP Content-Language header. If your intended audience speaks more than one language, the HTTP header allows you to use a comma-separated list of languages.